# How to increase query execution time of Presto in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, presto, apache-spark-dataset, presto-jdbc

I'm currently connecting to Presto using Spark. Our queries are getting timed out after `60m`, to increase query execution time I've set `query.max-execution-time` parameters in `getDBProperties()` like below

```
private def constructPrestoDataFrame(sparkSession : SparkSession, jobConfig : Config, query : String) : DataFrame = {
    sparkSession
      .read
      .jdbc(getPrestoConnectionUrl(jobConfig), query, getDBProperties(jobConfig))
  }

  private def getDBProperties(jobConfig : Config) : Properties = {
    val dbProperties = new Properties
    dbProperties.put("user", jobConfig.getString("presto.user"))
    dbProperties.put("password", jobConfig.getString("presto.password"))
    dbProperties.put("Driver", jobConfig.getString("presto.driver.name"))
    dbProperties.put("query.max-execution-time", "2d")

    dbProperties
  }

  private def getPrestoConnectionUrl(jobConfig : Config) : String = {
    s"jdbc:presto://${jobConfig.getString("presto.host")}:8443/${jobConfig.getString("presto.catalogue.name")}?SSL=true&SSLTrustStorePath=${jobConfig.getString("sslTrustStorePath")}"+
      "&SSLTrustStorePassword="+URLEncoder.encode(jobConfig.getString("sslTrustStorePassword"))
  }
```

When I run the job I'm getting exception saying `exception caught: Cause = null Message = Unrecognized connection property 'query.max-execution-time'`

We use `apache-spark-2.3.x`, `presto-jdbc-driver-300`.

Comment: isn't this part of the session properties of Presto? Or at least did you try it as session property? The key would be `query_max_execution_time` in that case

Comment: Yes, I tried with `query_max_execution_time`. I'm getting same exception.

Comment: @UninformedUser If my understanding is correct, the way we add `session properties` is same as how we add other data base properties (adding to `dbProperties` object)

Comment: from my understanding, and according to the docs, it only takes JDBS params because it's just for the JDBC driver: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html - so I think what you want to set is part of your Presto setup itself, there should be a properties file somewhere around used by your Presto instance.

Comment: I agree with your point @UninformedUser, but in my case I don't have access to change any configuration settings at presto instance level. If I can set the configuration within my connection/session scope, we are good

Answer (score 1):

Adding `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` to [`sessionVariables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-session.html#cj-conn-prop_sessionVariables) in the URL does the job for me:

```
jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{database}?sessionVariables=MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=123456666
```

Query to verify:

```
SELECT @@max_execution_time
```

Expected output:

```
+--------------------+ 
|@@max_execution_time| 
+--------------------+ 
| 123456666          | 
+--------------------+
```